# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CGI.Util'; 'CGI' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I am the author of [Pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/) - a Perl to Python translator and I'm currently trying to translate CGI.pm into Python.  The output file is CGI.py.  I am getting this error on this import:

```
perllib.init_package("CGI", is_class=True)  # Creates builtins.CGI = namespace

sys.path[0:0] = ["./PyModules"]
from CGI.Util import (ascii2ebcdic, ebcdic2ascii, escape, expires, make_attributes, rearrange, rearrange_header, unescape)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CGI.Util'; 'CGI' is not a package
```

The `PyModules` directory contains `CGI/Util.py`.  Note that the name of the file generated that contains this code is `CGI.py`.  I understand that this is a no-no, and also note that `perllib.init_package("CGI"...)` creates a `CGI` attribute of `builtins` such that when you mention `CGI` you get that namespace.

So my question is - any idea how to avoid this issue?  I'm thinking of using __import__ for this case if that's the only option, and by "this case" I mean that the filename I'm generating is the same as the prefix of the thing I'm importing -or- I have a namespace by that name (not sure which is causing the issue - probably both).  Insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe see if there's a function that solves this for you in [the importlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

Comment: I don’t see anything there that does from X import Y - the \_\_import__ function supports that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, in order to use a sub-module, you have to have the parent in a package.  This means that `CGI.py` should be instead put in `CGI/__init__.py` if CGI has sub-modules, then `import CGI` will still work, but also `from CGI.Util import ...` will then properly find `CGI/Util.py`.